# using trigger for filter data

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a column `suhu_udara` which is `not null` with the value of decimal.

I want have a code for this logical using trigger before insert in mysql like this :

if value new.suhu_udara - value last.suhu_udara >5 then set new suhu_udara into null so the value will be rejected in my table. 
I try this code but it doesn't work

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `filter` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `data_cuaca` FOR EACH ROW
if (new.suhu_udara - last.suhu_udara > 5) then
set new.tekanan_udara = null;
end if
```

Comment: where did I put begin and end ? Beside that , I think old.value just for trigger in update , is it true?

Comment: You might need a cursor for that,but im not very familiar with cursors

Comment: cursors like what ? I don't understand

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html

Comment: thank you, but still I can't declare the last value of `suhu_udara`